# Is SQL Server CDC viable for whole DB?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I don't think this has been answered before. My oganisation uses an operational system hosted by a 3rd party through a SaaS arrangement. We want to have a replication of our production DB in our own network and I am looking at options for this.
We have looked at CDC, but from what I understand each table that is tracked creates a table in the cdc schema that holds the change records. To then keep my local copy of the DB in sync we'd need to build and maintain 100s (DB is ~300 tables) of SSIS flows to process each one individually, which seems absurd.
I don't think the group availablility will work given the separation of the DBs.
Is CDC the best way to go, or is there something else I am missing?
Cheers, Clinton

Comment: CDC is a very low level granular form of replication. There are higher levels of replication such as log shipping, transactional replication. None of these use log tables or SSIS. How up to date does the copy have to be? You could just backup your source DB and restore it every day

Comment: That was our first thought, but the file is quite large - we did a one off transfer and it took several hours to trasnfer so was not very practical as a daily process, and we want to have the flexibility to ramp up to hourly in the future.

Comment: With transactional replication you do one full snapshot at the start then you apply smaller transactional changes. How up to date does your target need to be (daily? hourly?) Is  your target for reporting only (read only)? If not, what happens when the two database get out of sync?

Comment: Sorry I just saw hourly.... so you might find the snapshot takes a long time but the transactional takes less than an hour.

Comment: Thanks Nick. The transactional replication looks promising from a quick initial read. I will investigate further.
Yes, this is entriely for reporting. No changes will be made to data on our side.

Comment: You might also want to look at always on availability groups with asynchronous secondary.

Comment: Thanks Steve, my quick read of availablty groups suggested the servers need to be on the same cluster? We are physically separated from production and talking over the internet, can it work in this situation?